# How to use group by in two columns resulting for any one particular column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a table `T1` which has 3 column `bpm_no`, `winame` and `entrytime`. Each `bpm_no` is opened at certain `winame` (stages) and the `winame` might be different or might be the same (repeating). And its opening time is captured in `entrytime` column. I have another look up table `T2` where one `bpm_no` will display at which particular `winame` the `bpm_no` currently exists.

Idea is to extract a data using both the tables to make the final table, where it will display the `bpm_no`, its current `winame`, and the `winame` entry date which would be the minimum. Please refer the example below

Lookup table T2:

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|      bpm_no         |     winame       |
+---------------------+------------------+
|      abc_0011       |      rm          |
|     lmn_0012        |      archive     |
|      xyz_0013       |      lmn         |
```

Table T1:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      bpm_no         |     winame       |   entrytime      |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      abc_0011       |      pending     | 07 June 18       |
|      abc_0011       |      rm          | 06 June 18       |
|      abc_0011       |      rm          | 11 June 18       |
|      lmn_0012       |      archive     |  9 May 18        |
|      lmn_0012       |      rm          |  10 May 18       |
|      lmn_0012       |      archive     |  10 May 18       |
|      xyz_0013       |      lmn         |  11 May 18       |
|      xyz_0013       |      lmn         |  10 May 18       |
|      xyz_0013       |      intro       |  06 May 18       |
```

Desired output:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      bpm_no         |     winame       |   entrytime      |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|      abc_0011       |      rm          | 06 June 18       |
|      lmn_0012       |      archive     | 9 May 18         |
|      xyz_0013       |      lmn         |  10 May 18       |
```

Here in this case, I have 3 bpm_no abc_0011,lmn_0012,xyz_0013. If you look at look up table T2, the bpm_no lies at rm,archive and lmn winame respectively. In the table T2, it shows the history of bpm_no as from which winame has the bpm_no crossed and what was the entry_time for the same. So, we have to pick only those winame from T1 which is equally lying in Lookup table T2 and then have to calculate and store the minimum entrytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.bpm_no,
    t1.winame,
    min(entrytime) min_entrytime
FROM
    t1 JOIN t2
        ON t1.bpm_no = t2.bpm_no
            AND t1.winame = t2.winame

GROUP BY
    t1.bpm_no,
    t1.winame;
```

Comment: @MdKamranAzam Welcome, glad that I could help.